# Is there some documented logic to kubectl syntax?

Tags: kubectl

Looking at this documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-env-em-

it says

```
Update deployment 'registry' with a new environment variable

kubectl set env deployment/registry STORAGE_DIR=/local
```

Why is there an equals symbol for "STORAGE_DIR is /local" but a slash for "deployment is registry"?

Are they arbitrary?

E.g. could you mix and match as follows:

`kubectl set env deployment=registry STORAGE_DIR//local`?

Also, why does `deployment/registry` come in between the `set env` subcommand and the environment variable being set?

Answer (score 0):

Using resource `type/name` is a Kubernetes (and `kubectl`) convention to disambiguate e.g. `pod/foo`, `[custom-resource]/foo` from `deployment/foo` where this may be significant.

You'll see `type/name` appear frequently in `kubectl get` output. IIRC the `/` can be replaced with space e.g. `kubectl get deployment foo` and the type can likely (!?) be omitted if there's no ambiguity.

Because the `kubectl set env` command `set`'s env var values in the resource, `=` is used here to convey the assignment as conveyed by the usage `kubectl set env RESOURCE/NAME KEY_1=VAL_1 ... KEY_N=VAL_N`.

IMO this command follows conventions: `[binary] [group] [[sub-group]] [resource] [flags]`. In this case, there's no need to prefix the `type/name` with a flag (i.e. `--resource=type/name`) because the resource is required. One tweak, I'd consider for consistency is to prefix `--env=KEY_N=VAL_N` as this would be consistent with other flags e.g. `--namespace=bar` but...